# Home network cabling and breakout box

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I just moved into a condo unit and saw this box in the electrical & network closet, there is no explanation from the previous owner how they did the networking, so I want to seek help from the forum here. Is it for networking or analog TV or phone lines?

The box:

[image: The box]

In addition, my house layout is as follows, the fibre moderm is left of kitchen, through a hidden cable in the wall, it is connected to the network RJ45 port in the living room and I put a router there for my daily usage.

House layout:

[image: House layout]

There are some other "ports" but I don't know if it is for phone line or RJ45 internet around the house, I can't see them because they are behind some fixed-on-the-wall furnitures.

Comment: Looks like telephone connection. Also may be RS232/485/etc. connection to heat/electricity/etc. metering devices.

Comment: I cant be sure, but it looks somewhat like phone cabling or rs485 - the latter I have no knowledge of.  Pair 1 for phone cabling is blue/white   Its not notwork cabling or RS232 cabling because there is not a 1:1 mapping (some pairs are jumpered on the right side of the krone block)

Comment: RJ45 is a connectir standard (looks like ethernet). RJ45 does not tell you if it can be used for networking, but certainly this is not ethernet compatible. (ethernet requires a minimum of 2 pairs, and pairs are twised, color coded and not 1:1.

Comment: Hi davidgo, tks for the explanation, I searched that for ethernet cable, it needs the "orange, green, blue, brown" twisted with white cables? If I happen to be able to find those from the cables in the above box, (and assume they are not cut in the middle, i can turn this box as a swtich?